# Find the unique solution to the IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Find the unique solution to the IVP

$t^3y'' + e^ty' + t^4y = 0$
$y(1) = 0$
$y'(1) = 0$

Any help would be great..I am lost on how to do this problem.. at first I was going to try to divide by $t^4$ but now I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that $y \equiv 0$ does it. Please don't hate me.

Comment: And, therefore, $0 = y''(0) = y'''(0) = ... = y^{(n)}(0)$.